# Intitutive idea behind the build heap function

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I want to know about the following statement in build heap function

```
for i=A.length/2 downto 1
```

As this step was deduced by hit & trial to find out the parent of leaves or there was something else in the mind of the person who developed this algorithm
Below is build heap function-

```
Build_Max_Heap(A)
A.heap_size=A.length
for i=A.length/2 downto 1
Max_Heapify(A,i)
```

Comment: It's basically a dynamic programming solution. The reason to study algorithms is not so much to memorize specific solutions to specific problems, but rather to develop a mental toolbox of approaches to solving problems. DP is one such approach.

Comment: @rici: I am not sure if your comment is for this question.

Comment: @Aravind: why not? DP effectively inverts (or, if you prefer, predicts) recursion. Maybe I'm cross-eyed, but that was my thought process about heapify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nodes of the second half of the array are leaves(explanation follows in next paragraph) and are thus trivially 1-node max heaps already, and hence Max_Heapify need not be done for them.
Even if you call Max_Heapify for those nodes, no harm in terms of time complexity as the leaf nodes have no nodes below and Max_Heapify would return immediately anyway.

Mathematically it's easy to establish that the second half of the array are leaves by the way summation of a Geometric Progression works. Recall that a heap is a complete binary tree, which means it will have all nodes filled in each level, except possibly the last level, in which it will be filled partially from left to right. For sake of simplicity, let's assume the number of nodes in our heap as 2^N. Clearly this tree has N levels with all levels filled.

First level has 2^0 node

Second level has 2^1 nodes

Third level has 2^2 nodes

N-1 level has 2^N-2 nodes

Nth level has 2^N-1 nodes

```
 Sum of the count of nodes in all levels except last = 2^0 + 2^1...+ 2^N-2
                                                     = 2^N-1 - 1
```

This is the number of nodes in the last level off by one. That is, the the total number of nodes in all levels except the last is almost same as the number of nodes in just the last level, which directly implies that the last level must have half the total number of all nodes in the heap in it. By this observation, we get A.length/2.